# Перетаскивание графического объекта

Tags: c++

Подскажите, каким образом можно реализовать перемещение объекта (drag and drop), например геометрической фигуры или рисунка? Именно перемещение, то есть, захватив объект, произвольно перетаскивать и оставить его там, где отпустил мышку.

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от используемого апи у вас должно быть три обработчика:

- `onMouseDown` - кнопка мыши нажата
- `onMouseMove(dx, dy)` - перемещение мыши
- `onMouseUp` - кнопка мыши отпущена

В первом (если надо) определяете, находится ли объект под мышью, и "фиксируете" объект (например, запоминаете его адрес в указатель P).
Во втором делаете

```
if(P) { P->x += dx; P->y += dy; }
```

В третьем зануляете P.

Идея очень простая. Детали реализации могут различаться, но с ними элементарно разобраться (см., например, MSDN или документацию по используемой библиотеке GUI).

Если конкретнее укажете используемое апи/библиотеку, то и ответ, возможно, будет подробнее.

Примерно так это будет выглядить на Win API (извиняюсь за форматирование, непонятно, не могу разобраться, как тут код писать)

```
DisplayObject* g_object = NULL;
DisplayObject* g_active = NULL;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {   
    // Стандартный код создания окна

    g_object = new DisplayObject;  
    g_object->moveTo(0,0);
}

int WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if(message == WM_PAINT) {
        // Как-то отрисовали объект
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;

        BeginPaint(&ps);
        g_object->draw(&ps);
        EndPaint(&ps);
    }
    else if(message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {    
        g_active = NULL;
        if(g_object->containsPoint(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam)))        
        {
            g_active = g_object;

            TRACKMOUSEEVENT trackEvent;

            trackEvent.cbSize = sizeof(trackEvent);
            trackEvent.hwndTrack = hWnd;
            trackEvent.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE;
            trackEvent.dwHoverTime = 0;

            TrackMouseEvent(&trackEvent);
        }
    }
    else if(message == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        // Допустим, что lParam содержит смещения (не помню уже точно)

        if(g_active)
            g_active->move(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
    }
    else if( message == WM_LBUTTONUP || message == WM_MOUSELEAVE)
    {
        g_active = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: а,можно посмотреть код? тоже интересует такое,но хочется покопаться в коде,пусть и самом простом

Comment: Дописал пример кода. Винапи - не самый наглядный вариант, но больше ни на чем практически готового кода у меня в закромах не валялось.

Comment: @alphard Чтобы отформатировать код, надо выделить его мышкой и нажать на кнопку 101010 или в любом удобном для Вас редакторе добавить уровень идентации (четыре пробела) для всего кода.